# Password encryption in MySQL and PHP over HTTPS

Tags: php, mysql, md5, hash, sha1

Is it really necessary to encrypt passwords using `md5()` or `sha1()` WITH SALT (or even at all) if the connection takes place over HTTPS?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that this is not _encryption_, it's hashing. Hashes are not decryptable into the original text like encryption is, it's a one-way process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If somebody hacks into your server, or gets ahold of a backup, and the passwords aren't aren't hashed with a salt, then they will have access to all your users passwords.  It's very much necessary to salt and hash your passwords. Probably more important than using HTTPS to authenticate.

They actually should both be used, as they solve completely different problems. HTTPS is used to protect the password as it travels over the internet to your servers.  Hashing and salting is used to protect the password when it is stored on your servers.

Comment: Remember that having a strong SALT effectively increasing the strength of your user's passwords.  A minimum length for a SALT should be 12 ASCII characters; do not use Unicode characters.  An encrypted database of passwords also makes it more difficult for someone to try to break it with a `Rainbow table`.

Comment: I am still unsure of the following, if you use a form which submits the password as plain text using POST over HTTPS, is this also classified as insecure?

Comment: It's less secure than using HTTPs.  But it depends on what you're trying to secure.  For a bank it's not secure enough to just use HTTP.  If you're just doing logins for a message board, plain old HTTP may be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Consider HTTPS to be the equivalent of an armored car transferring data back and forth between the server and the client browser. You can make that armored car as tough and secure as you want, but if the server and/or the client are a tent in the middle of an army of thieves, you've achived ZERO in the way of security - the thieves will ignore the armored car and just cut through the tent wall and walk away with your precious valuables.

Answer (score 0):

Encryption of passwords is a *very* good idea even if you're transmitting over a HTTPS connection. The reason is that it is possible an attacker can gain access to the database, and thus view its contents without intercepting the connection.